# Using parts of a file as nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

First part: the nodes

Each node is presented in one line as follows: number, phone number, name, city, total time spent; where number is a sequential number starting from 1 that identifies the node. Total time spent is the total number of seconds in calls initiated by the phone number.

Second part: the edges

Each edge is presented in one line as follows: number of origin, number of destination, weight; where number origin and destination are numbers identifying the nodes in the first part of the file.

An example of the callgraph.txt file could look like this. Note that the nodes are sorted by phone number.

```
2, 7801234567, Ameneh Gholipour Shahraki, Hinton, 198473
7, 7801236789, Stuart Johnson, Saint Albert, 64399
4, 7803214567, Md Toukir Imam, Sherwood Park, 179532
8, 7804321098, Hamman Samuel, Stony Plain, 57909
1, 7804922860, Osmar Zaiane, Edmonton, 250068
5, 7807890123, Elham Ahmadi, Devon, 129370
9, 7808765432, Amir Hossein Faghih Dinevari, Beaumont, 62552
6, 7808907654, Weifeng Chen, Spruce Grove, 121726
3, 7809876543, Farrukh Ahmed, Edson, 190211

2, 7, 40425
2, 4, 21618
2, 8, 34186
2, 1, 34291
2, 5, 24286
2, 9, 67786
2, 6, 21983
2, 3, 35614
7, 4, 32851
7, 8, 27293
7, 1, 45367
```

Now the first part I completed easily as seen:

```
customers=open('customers.txt','r')
    calls=open('calls.txt.','r')
    nodes= {}
    name={}
    city={}
    total_spent_time={}
    with open("customers.txt") as fp:
        for line in fp:
            number = line.split(";")[0]
            if number not in nodes:
                nodes[number] = len(nodes) + 1
            rows=line.split(";")
            name[rows[0]]=rows[1]
            city[rows[0]]=rows[2].strip("\n")
    with open("calls.txt") as fp2:    
        for lines in fp2:
            rows2=lines.split(";")
            if rows2[1] not in total_spent_time:
                total_spent_time[rows2[1]]=int(rows2[3])
            elif rows2[1]  in total_spent_time:
                total_spent_time[rows2[1]]+=int(rows2[3])
        print(total_spent_time)
```

But it is the second part I am having most trouble with; for instance I have to assign a node number to every unique phone #, and then as seen in the example file calculate for how long each node talked with another and so on.

The file that I got the unique numbers from is here:
http://pastebin.com/xMx15nCS

And the file which contains thousands of calls between these numbers is here:
 http://pastebin.com/RSMnXDtq

Where the second row of calls.txt is the initiator #, third row the receiver # and fourth row the amount of seconds talked in total between these two numbers.

How would I go about assigning nodes, calculating the total amount of time between each of the numbers, and at the same time using them as nodes?

EDIT: I thought about making a tuple between caller and receiver and it worked! but now I need to assign node numbers to them, how would I go about that?

here is what I added:

```
nodes_g={}
    with open("calls.txt") as fp3:
        for line in fp3:
            rows3=line.split(";")
            x,node1,node2,sec,y=line.split(";")
            if node1 not in nodes_g:
                nodes_g[node1]=node2
    print(nodes_g)
```

EDIT2: Attempted to combine "node" dictionary with another one to calculate total amount of times between each number; did not go well as I received an error saying that dictionaries are unhashable in python. Can anybody tell me a workaround?

```
nodes_g={}
complete={}
with open("calls.txt") as fp3:
    for line in fp3:
        rows3=line.split(";")
        x,node1,node2,sec,y=line.split(";")
        if node1 not in nodes_g:
            nodes_g[node1]=node2
        else:
            nodes_g[node1]=node2
        for k,v in nodes_g.items():
            if node1 in nodes_g and node1!=node2:
                nodes_g[node1]=node2
        for k,v in nodes_g.items():
            if node1 and node2 in nodes_g:
                complete[nodes_g]=sec
            else:
                complete[nodes_g]+=sec

print(complete)
```

EDIT3:
I tried using tuples nested in a dict but for some reason it doesn't add the value but merely replaces it by the value on the next line without adding them!?

```
nodes_g={}
complete={}
with open("calls.txt") as fp3:
    for line in fp3:
        rows3=line.split(";")
        x,node1,node2,sec,y=line.split(";")
        if node1 not in nodes_g:
            nodes_g[node1,node2]=int(sec)
        if node1 in nodes_g and node2 in nodes_g:
            nodes_g[node1,node2]+=int(sec)
        print(nodes_g)



print(nodes_g)
```

Comment: Could you make more clear about your problem? I'm confused. Telephones are nodes, and talks among telephones are directed edges between nodes. Is that right?  Why do you think "now I need to assign node numbers to them"? They are not nodes but edges.

Comment: @Fumu7   Well each unique number is a node. And I have to calculate the amount of time of talk between each unique number. Any thoughts?

Comment: A Tuple of origin and destination can be used to identify the edge between them. Why do you need a number instead of a Tuple of origin and destination?

Comment: @Fumu7   The question is asking to assign an int number instead of just using the actual phone #. Could you show me what you have in mind?

Comment: Is a unique number assigned to actual telephone number in each lines of first part of "callgraph.txt file"?  I understand that number 2 to  telephone number 7801234567, number 7 to telephone number 7801236789, and so on.  A tuple (2,7) identifies an edge, a talk,  from  telephone number 7801234567 to  telephone number 7801236789 from your example.

Comment: @Fumu7 Yes! That is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69704/discussion-between-no-sleep-and-fumu-7).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want it the total time for each distinct (destination, recipient) pair (2,7 ...) from the first line of the second part of your sample file ... then I'd create a dictionary with the tuples ((2,7), (2,4), (2,8), etc, as keys and the sums of those conversations (initially set to (40425, 21618, 34186 respectively) as values.

In other words if the first call was from point 2, to point 7 and lasted 40425 seconds(?) then just create a dictionary entry with the key `(2,7)` and the initial value of `40425` ... if you encounter another call from 2 to 7 then add it's value to your sum (`my_report[(2,7)]+=XXXX` for example).

This would yield separate entries for calls from 7 to 2.  However, you use `tuple(sorted((x,y))` as the key to sum calls in both directions under one key.  In other words to yield a report of all distinct pairings regardless of which end initiated the call).

Incidentally you can reduce `if *somekey* not in *mydict*: ...` clutter using: `mydict[somekey] = mydict.get(somekey, 0) + value` ... which will maintain the sum and supply a default value of zero for any key that was not previous present.  That's a common Pythonic micro-optimization which could replace four lines near the end of your code from "EDIT3" with a single, relatively easy to read line.

I will confess that I have no confidence that I'm interpreting your intentions correctly.  I note that your code examples are splitting on **;** and your sample data fragments appear to be **,** delimited.  I presume that this is just some editing/pasting errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function # make example work for Python 2.7+ or 3.x
# ...
# ...
my_report = dict()
for line in fp3:
     try:
         row = tuple([int(x) for x in line.split(",", 3)])
     except ValueError, e:
         print("Corrupt data?: %s" % line, file=sys.stderr)
         continue
     key = row[:2]
     my_report[key] = my_report.get(key, 0) + row[3]
 # print(my_report)
 for node_pair, total in sorted(my_reports.iteritems()):
     print("%s: %d" % (node_pair, total))
```

(Although you might prefer some formatting and sorting of the output; as shown).

Comment: Well firstly I don't know how many combinations there are of tuples since the file contains thousands of calls; so creating a new dict for all of them is out of the question. Would you care to show what you had in mind in code? I am having a hard time understanding what you want me to answer.

Comment: Thousands of these pairwise tuples (as keys) is not going to be an issue for any modern computing system.  Even a few million would not take up excessive memory or CPU time on a modern desktop or server.

I'm editing my posting to show a simple code sample that would work with the second part of your sample data.

Comment: Thank you, I just couldn't visualize what you were saying.

Comment: The code is untested.  I'm trying to convey the concept reasonably not write it for you.

Comment: Well i figured it out using a tuple pair as key in a dict and then frozenset function on it. Thanks for the help! :)